# Sonar analysis failing - unable to request /batch_bootstrap/properties

Tags: maven, jenkins, sonarqube

We've been analyzing our projects with SonarQube for several months now without any problems. Since this morning, analysis is failing with this error:

```
Unable to request: /batch_bootstrap/properties?project=TalkManagement:TalkManagementService&dryRun=false
```

This is happening since we upgraded our Amazon EC2 instance to Ubuntu 14.04 and Oracle JDK8. We're running SonarQube 4.3.2 against a MySQL database, Maven 3.1 and Jenkins 1.571.

Following is the logs from running Maven on our project:

```
[DEBUG] [13:12:25.839] Download: http://ec2-0.0.0.0.compute-1.amazonaws.com:9000/batch_bootstrap/properties?project=TalkManagement:TalkManagementService&amp;dryRun=false (no proxy)
[DEBUG] [13:12:29.334] Updating semaphore batch-TalkManagement:TalkManagement-parent
[DEBUG] [13:12:39.372] Updating semaphore batch-TalkManagement:TalkManagement-parent
[DEBUG] [13:12:46.127] Release semaphore on project : org.sonar.api.resources.Project@2fa1044d[id=429,key=TalkManagement:TalkManagement-parent,qualifier=TRK], with key batch-TalkManagement:TalkManagement-parent
[DEBUG] [13:12:46.531] To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] has been forcibly deregistered
[ERROR] Unable to request: /batch_bootstrap/properties?project=TalkManagement:TalkManagementService&dryRun=false
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Talk Management System ............................ FAILURE [12:22.555s]
[INFO] TalkManagement .................................... SUCCESS [1:17.314s]
[INFO] TalkManagementServiceApi .......................... SUCCESS [13.759s]
[INFO] TalkManagementService ............................. SUCCESS [6:07.446s]
[INFO] TalkUIAutomationTest .............................. SUCCESS [7.225s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 20:53.855s
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Aug 06 13:13:00 EDT 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 39M/494M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.3.1:sonar (default-cli) on project TalkManagement-parent: Unable to request: /batch_bootstrap/properties?project=TalkManagement:TalkManagementService&dryRun=false: Read timed out -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.3.1:sonar (default-cli) on project TalkManagement-parent: Unable to request: /batch_bootstrap/properties?project=TalkManagement:TalkManagementService&dryRun=false
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:216)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:318)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:153)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.launcher.Maven31Launcher.main(Maven31Launcher.java:132)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchStandard(Launcher.java:331)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:239)
    at jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven31Main.launch(Maven31Main.java:181)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:134)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:69)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:118)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:48)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:328)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:72)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Unable to request: /batch_bootstrap/properties?project=TalkManagement:TalkManagementService&dryRun=false
    at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.bootstrap.ExceptionHandling.handle(ExceptionHandling.java:37)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.bootstrap.RunnerBootstraper.execute(RunnerBootstraper.java:136)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.SonarMojo.execute(SonarMojo.java:194)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: org.sonar.api.utils.SonarException: Unable to request: /batch_bootstrap/properties?project=TalkManagement:TalkManagementService&dryRun=false
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.ServerClient.request(ServerClient.java:92)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.ServerClient.request(ServerClient.java:82)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.ServerClient.request(ServerClient.java:78)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ModuleSettings.downloadSettings(ModuleSettings.java:82)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ModuleSettings.addProjectProperties(ModuleSettings.java:77)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ModuleSettings.init(ModuleSettings.java:63)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ModuleSettings.<init>(ModuleSettings.java:59)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector.newInstance(AbstractInjector.java:145)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$1.run(ConstructorInjector.java:342)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(AbstractInjector.java:270)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjector.java:364)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.getComponentInstance(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:56)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.getComponentInstance(AbstractBehavior.java:64)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.getComponentInstance(Stored.java:91)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:698)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:646)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:677)
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.getComponentByType(ComponentContainer.java:198)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ModuleScanContainer.addCoreComponents(ModuleScanContainer.java:86)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doBeforeStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:73)
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:90)
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:77)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:199)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:194)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:192)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:187)
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:92)
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:77)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ScanTask.scan(ScanTask.java:56)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:44)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:82)
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:92)
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:77)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.BootstrapContainer.executeTask(BootstrapContainer.java:175)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.BootstrapContainer.doAfterStart(BootstrapContainer.java:163)
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:92)
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:77)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.startBatch(Batch.java:92)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:74)
    at org.sonar.runner.batch.IsolatedLauncher.execute(IsolatedLauncher.java:48)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:87)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.run(BatchLauncher.java:75)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.doExecute(BatchLauncher.java:69)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.execute(BatchLauncher.java:50)
    at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.doExecute(EmbeddedRunner.java:102)
    at org.sonar.runner.api.Runner.execute(Runner.java:100)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.bootstrap.RunnerBootstraper.execute(RunnerBootstraper.java:132)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$10.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1888)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$10.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1883)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getChainedException(HttpURLConnection.java:1882)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1455)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1439)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480)
[JENKINS] Archiving /home/ubuntu/.jenkins/workspace/TalkServiceCI/TalkUIAutomationTest/pom.xml to TalkManagement/TalkUIAutomationTest/1.1.8/TalkUIAutomationTest-1.1.8.pom
[JENKINS] Archiving /home/ubuntu/.jenkins/workspace/TalkServiceCI/TalkUIAutomationTest/target/TalkUIAutomationTest-1.1.8.jar to TalkManagement/TalkUIAutomationTest/1.1.8/TalkUIAutomationTest-1.1.8.jar
    at org.sonar.api.utils.HttpDownloader$BaseHttpDownloader$HttpInputSupplier.getInput(HttpDownloader.java:274)
    at org.sonar.api.utils.HttpDownloader$BaseHttpDownloader$HttpInputSupplier.getInput(HttpDownloader.java:235)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.ServerClient.request(ServerClient.java:88)
    ... 88 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:150)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:121)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:286)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:701)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:647)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1534)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1439)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getHeaderField(HttpURLConnection.java:2929)
    at java.net.URLConnection.getContentEncoding(URLConnection.java:523)
    at org.sonar.api.utils.HttpDownloader$BaseHttpDownloader$HttpInputSupplier.getInput(HttpDownloader.java:272)
    ... 90 more
```

When accessing http://ec2-0.0.0.0.compute-1.amazonaws.com:9000/batch_bootstrap/properties?project=TalkManagement:TalkManagementService&dryRun=false directly through a browser or curl, the response is indeed slow but never longer than 10 seconds.

**Edit** Actually when getting this URL while an analysis is running, it can take over a minute to return an answer!

We have tried adding the following properties to our pom.xml file:

```
    <sonar.dryRun.readTimeout>60</sonar.dryRun.readTimeout>
    <sonar.preview.readTimeout>60</sonar.preview.readTimeout>
```

It doesn't look like it's helping.

This is a multi-module project and the /batch_bootstrap/properties URL has been called successfully on other modules before this last failure.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

**Edit**

Upgrading to Sonar 4.4, Maven Sonar plugin 2.4 and Jenkins 1.574 gives the same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the EC2 instance was overloaded (CPU and memory were floored) and Sonar couldn't answer the /batch_bootstrap/properties URL in under 60 seconds, hence the failure. We migrated to a larger EC2 instance and the problem has disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

Or simply try this,

```
select * from semaphores
```

This will list the stuck build, you'll be able to see project name, kee. If there is any row and that matches your project note down the id. Then delete it from the semaphores table

```
delete from semaphores where id  = $id
```

Sometimes, when job is killed with jenkins you get this problem.